# How to draw a shape (ellipse) in MKMapView?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, mkmapview, uibezierpath, mkoverlay

I would like to draw a shape in the MKMapView. In a standalone view, I can draw a circle with the user "pinch to zoom". Now, I have a toggle button that enables/disables zoomEnabled on the MKMapView. This toggle allows the user to pinch to zoom a circle in the map. The problem is that when the toggle is disabled, I cannot use the map functionality anymore. I've seen stuff with MKOverlayView and core layer, but not sure what to use. I currently have a CircleView subclassing UIView and draws a circle with CGContextAddArc in drawRect.

Comment: Are you just drawing a circle? The typical solution for that is to use `addOverlay` of a `MKCircle` and then implement a `viewForOverlay` that creates a `MKCircleView`.

Comment: Yea, I'm drawing a circle. I tried the MKCircle and it's not really what I'm trying to do. It's too slow. I want the user to have a circle being drawn as they pinch to zoom. Pinching to zoom should move/resize the circle with their fingers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714374/how-to-bring-uibezierpath-to-the-back-of-a-mkannotation-object/14726964#14726964 It seems like this is the proper path but not really sure.